# What does "bm_start" do in a bash script?

Tags: bash, git

Studying the [Github backup-utils](https://github.com/github/backup-utils) I found the command `bm_start` inside their scripts. [This](https://github.com/github/backup-utils/blob/be3397cf4b835270aef120c5b5824897cd9fcabd/bin/ghe-backup#L118-L121) is an example that uses the `bm_start` and `bm_end`, with some other code between them.

According to the [project page](https://github.com/github/backup-utils/blob/be3397cf4b835270aef120c5b5824897cd9fcabd/README.md#backup-host-requirements), the pre-requisite to use the scripts is:

> Linux or other modern Unix operating system with bash, git, OpenSSH,
>   and rsync v2.6.4 or newer.

Where does this command come from? How does it work?
I could not find references to `bm_start` with `man` or `apropos`, nor by Googling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're shell functions defined in share/github-backup-utils/bm.sh, pulled in via share/github-backup-utils/ghe-backup-config.

Comment: Whoah! That explains why my current bash session was able to use the `bm_*` functions...I had not realized that the script was using `BASH_SOURCE` from another location. Thanks!